# Proguard not obfuscating room database class name

Tags: android, android-room, android-proguard

I have obfuscated my code with proguard but couple of classes are not obfuscated, like the ones referenced in AndroidManifest and also my

```
@Database(
entities = {User.class}, version = 3)
public abstract class LocalDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
```

I do not understand why `LocalDatabase` is not obfuscated.

Comment: I'd file a bug report on the Google issue tracker and post the issue link here so others can vote for it: https://issuetracker.google.com

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121099043